# Why is FindObjectOfType(MyType) not finding anything?

Tags: unity, c#

Why would I get the following log?

- Start OpponentMotionReceiver
- motion receiver not found
- true

---

```
    public class ScoreAnimation : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private OpponentMotionReceiver cachedObject;

        private void Start()
        {
            cachedObject = FindObjectOfType<OpponentMotionReceiver>();
        }

        private void OnDestroy()
        {
                var motionReceiver = FindObjectOfType<OpponentMotionReceiver>();

                if (motionReceiver == null)
                {
                    Debug.Log("motion receiver not found");
                }

                if(cachedObject != null)
                {
                    //prints true, another proof that the gameObject is active
                    Debug.Log(cachedObject.gameObject.activeInHierarchy);
                }
        }
    }

public class OpponentMotionReceiver : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private void Start()
        {
            Debug.Log("Start OpponentMotionReceiver");
        }

        private void OnDisable()
        {
            //never enters
            Debug.Log("OnDisable OpponentMotionReceiver");
        }

        private void OnDestroy()
        {
            //never enters
            Debug.Log("OnDestroy OpponentMotionReceiver");
        }
    }
```

P.S. This is extremely simplified version of the code so that the rest brings no confusion. If you need more details, I'd be pleased to answer you!

Comment: What do u actually want to do? Is that a GameObject? and do u want to find that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you are changing the scene right? Only at that time unity behaves like that.

Comment: yeah I am changing the scene but do you mean that FindObjectOfType doesn't work while loading another scene? Because I am more than confident that the OpponentMotionReceiver object neither gets deactivated nor destroyed.

Comment: exactly, I meant the same. My suggestion would be to keep that instance before changing the scene for use.

Comment: WOW :D literally tried some of the dumbest things but never expected FindObjectOfType not to work in case of loading a new scene, HAH :D So it appears that no matter if a gameObject is being active or inactive or destroyed, just FindObjectOfType doesn't work on loading a new scene, funny :D Thanks a lot :D